# PHP Warning: Division by zero in

Tags: php

```
function fctdeux(string $str)
{
    $nbr;

    $nbr = 0;
    while($str >= '0' && $str <= '9')
    {
        $nbr = $nbr * 10 + ($str - '0');
        $str++;
    }
    return $nbr;
}    

function testeur(string $expr)
    {
        $nbr;
        $nbr2;
        $op;

        $nbr = anal_number($expr);
        while($expr)
        {
            while($expr == ' ')
            {
                $expr++ ;
                $op = $expr;

                if($op != '/' && $op != '*' && $op != '%')
                return $nbr;
            }
            $expr++;
            $nbr2 = anal_number($expr);
            if($op = '/')
            {
            $nbr /= $nbr2;
            }else 
            if($op == '*')
            {
                $nbr *= $nbr2;
            }else
            {
                $nbr %= $nbr2;
            }
        }
        return $nbr;
    }
    echo eval_expr(2+3);
```

Hello I try to create a calculator for when call the function in end of code echo exemple(2+3)and in terminal call the file php exemple.php its writing result of calcul(5). I have this error :

> PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /home/username/project/project.php on line 125

its where I have

```
$nbr /= $nbr2;
```

in code

Comment: just noticed you have a while for what should be an if statement (`while $var == ''` should be an if)

Comment: ok =) i change this while per if but now i have this error : PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/username/project/project.php on line 98 its where writing         $nbr = $nbr * 10 + ($str - '0');

Comment: @EmelianFedorovich isn't it a mistake `if($op = '/')` that caused your issue? fix it with `if($op == '/')`

Comment: ok thanks but error its where  writing:       $nbr = $nbr * 10 + ($str - '0');

Comment: Instead using strings for calculation, try to use them as integer or float. You can do intval(string) to convert to an integer value or floatval(string) to convert to a float value.

Comment: @gustavo.lei ok how i can do this ?

Comment: I just said in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Division by 0 is impossible. How many nothings go into X? The answer is a mathematical melt down. However, you can catch it in your code:

```
if ($nbr2 == 0) {
    # code to either return an error message about using 0 to divide
    # or you could return NaN (not a number) as the value.
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't lie, it hit the divide query where a value = 0 (or null)